# How to play .qtch files?

Tags: streaming, cache, quicktime, file-extension

So I have qtch files that apparently were created with QT 7+ because they can't be played (with QT 7+ or VLC) just by renaming their extension (as [fileinfo.com](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/qtch) says).

Any solution out there ?

Answer (score -1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qtch) the QT 7+ .qtch format differs only in the first 16 bytes  compared to the QuickTime Player 6.x cache format.  Therefore I'd suggest trying this command (but make a backup of your .qtch file first):

```
printf '\000\000\000\024\146\164\171\160\063\147\160\064\000\000\004\000' \
| dd bs=16 count=1 conv=notrunc of=filetomodify.qtch
```

It modifies the first 16 bytes of `filetomodify.qtch` as described above.  After that, you can rename it to `.mov` and if you're lucky, playback will work.

Comment: I tried, not sure my syntax was correct. I still can't play it so I'm giving you a sample file (see link in question) so that you can try.

Comment: It didn't work for me either, I'm afraid.